# Angular 2 Radio Button not Initializing Correctly with Reactive Form

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular2-forms, ng-bootstrap

I am starting with Angular 2 and am currently using version 2.2.2

I am writing a reactive form, but I am not able to initialize the selected radio button. The page should load with a radio button selected, but this is not occurring.

I have been unable to locate the source of the problem. From code samples on the Web, I think this should be working. Here is a snippet of my code.

```
<form [formGroup]="consultaSolicitudesINETELForm"  (ngSubmit)="consulta(consultaSolicitudesINETELForm)">
<input type="radio" formControlName="criterio" value="1"  />
<input type="radio" formControlName="criterio" value="2"  />
<input type="radio" formControlName="criterio" value="3"  />
<input type="text" formControlName="folio" placeholder="folio" required>
 </form>
```

for the component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'my',
templateUrl: 'my.component.html',
styleUrls: ['my.component.css']
})
export class My implements OnInit {

myForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.buildForm();
}

buildForm(): void {

  this.consultaSolicitudesINETELForm = this.fb.group({
    criterio: ["2"],
    folio: ["TEST"],

  });

  this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));
  this.onValueChanged();

}
```

EDIT: 
 [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/e659lNlGI5VK1rGqMmLi?p=info) is a `plnkr`   I forked from an example where I added radio that does not run in my environment. The only difference I see there are version numbers.

EDIT2: 
OK, I found it has something to do with ng-bootstrap.  If I use NgbModule.forRoot() then the radio buttons are not initialized and don't work as expected, if I disable ng-bootstrap then they work, but as I use ng-bootstrap elsewhere I can't do that.

I went around it by using ng-bootstrap's own radio button group and re-designing the web page. I had the radio buttons placed inside a legend of various fieldsets and all content always visible. 
Now the radios  work kind of like tabs, displaying a different div depending on the current selection.

The original purpouse of the radio buttons was to select a working fieldset where all it's elements would be enabled and all others fieldsets' content disabled.

Comment: Your radios should have the same name as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is with ng-bootstrap and is tracked at https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1125

It's high priority for them.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. Could you please help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47388377/two-way-binding-not-working-in-ng-bootstrap-radio-button-in-an-angular-reactive/47388971#47388971