# Two way binding not working in ng-bootstrap radio button in an angular reactive form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap, angular-reactive-forms

I am developing an application with Angular 4, Bootstrap 4 and ngbootstrap. The html code -

```
<div class="container">
  <form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(myForm.value)">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <legend class="col-form-legend col-sm-2">Required</legend>
        <div class="btn-group col-sm-2" ngbRadioGroup name="isRequired" formControlName="isRequired">
          <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
            <input ngbButton type="radio" name="radio" [value]="true">Yes
          </label>
          <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
            <input ngbButton type="radio" name="radio" [value]="false">No
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
          <i class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-lg"></i>
          Save
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </form>
</div>
```

The controller

```
 private buildForm() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      isRequired: [],
    });
  }
```

In the ngOnInit() hook of the controller I call the buildForm() method. Then I make a Http get request and fetch a value for the isRequired field. If the fetch is successful I call the following method to set the value of the radio button.

```
private loadFormData() {
    this.myForm.patchValue({
      isRequired: this.variable.isRequired,
    });
}
```

> The problem -  Lets assume the value of isRequired = true. This value
>   gets fetched properly and the radio gets initialized with this value
>   on form load. However, if the user changes the value (isRequired =
>   false) the field still retains the previous value (isRequired = true).

This works fine if I use the following code -

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <legend class="col-form-legend col-sm-2">Required</legend>
      <input type="radio" formControlName="isRequired" value="true"> Yes
      <input type="radio" formControlName="isRequired" value="false"> No
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#the-data-model-and-the-form-model

Comment: @ranakrunal9. I am following the reactive forms radio button example as shown on this link --> https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/buttons/examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that this problem is caused by popper.js
The official documentation of ng-bootstrap strongly advises against including it.

Please read the documentation provided [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

As per the [The data model and the form model](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#the-data-model-and-the-form-model) guide for Reactive Forms

`User changes flow from the DOM elements to the form model, not to the data model. The form controls never update the data model.`

Which means that when user select any value from radio your variable `this.variable.isRequired` is not get updated. To get form value you have to use `this.myForm.value` or you have to use `ngModel` on radio as explained on [ng-bootstrap buttons](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/buttons/examples).

Comment: this.variable is the object that is fetched from the database and it contains the initial value for the radio button. When the form is saved I am checking the myForm.value.isRequired.

Comment: can I use ngModel and formControlName together?